# How to get a SSL certificate to be verified in Python?

Tags: python, ssl, certificates

I've got an inexpensive certificate from EssentialSSL (Comodo is the CA) and I was surprised to discover that Python didn't recognize it.

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:509: error:14090086:SSL
routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

The certificate seems to be properly recognized by all major browsers, still Python does not validate it.

If possible I would prefer a simple install solution like the one of installing a package or a script.

I was a little bit surprised not to see Comodo in the default list of recognized CA certs, all major (5) browsers accept it but not Ubuntu wget/python/... (openssl i guess is the cause).

Comment: Comodo certs are present in Ubuntu, it could be that Python doesn't validate certificates based off the certificates available to the operating system.


Alternatively, your certificate may not be part of a chain that leads back to one of the 3 Comodo certs that Ubuntu trusts.

Comment: @jackweirdy please check my comments from the response, it seems that Comodo Certificate is not included in the list, I also have a sample test file.

Comment: Added bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates/+bug/1261855

Comment: run `ls -l /etc/ssl/certs/ | grep -i comodo`. You should see a number of comodo certificates there.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Debian package [*ca-certificates*](http://packages.debian.org/ca-certificates) which will incorporate (beside others) all CA certificates which Mozilla Firefox/Thunderbird/etc. uses.

You can use the certificate file (all certificates in one, PEM formatted) in Python as follows:

```py
ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock,  
                           ca_certs="/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt",  
                           cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED  
                          )
```

Comment: Where do you add that so the changes are system wide?

Comment: This is part of another library, I will test it first in order to see if this solves the problem and if true I will have to fix python distribution to make it work for any module.

Comment: I tried your approach but it seems that the Comodo certificate is not inside `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` -- you are free to test against `https://sbarnea.com` -- my OS X python validates the certificate but Ubuntu doesn't.

Comment: Take a look at this test file https://gist.github.com/ssbarnea/8007689 it fails all test relates to my domain on Ubuntu which means that the `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` does NOT contain COMODO certificates.